# AWS dynamoDB to Athena Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I've just started to use AWS, I have a question.
I'm trying to send data from DynamoDB (Account A) to Athena (Account B).

What I would like to do is,

- Transfer and update everyday the tables which are stored in Account A's DynamoDB TO ANOTHER ACCOUNT which is Account B.
- Account B is going to execute queries in Athena with the tables received from Account A.

Do you have any solution ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can not *transfer* data to Athena, which does not hold data itself.

If the query data source is in the same account, Athena Federated Query would be useful, but it does not seem to be supported cross-account yet.

So for your case, export DynamoDB table to S3 like [this aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/).

Then query S3 data using Athena.

Amazon EventBridge can be used for everyday scheduled actions.